# Valgrind throws Invalid write of size 8 using smart pointers

Tags: c++11

I am trying to implement a binary tree with the following code:

```
Node* Node::addLeft(int v){
   left = make_shared<Node> (v).get();
   //cout<<"set left "<<left->value<<endl;
   left->parent=this;
   return this;
}
```

When running valgrind, I've got the following report:

```
==18345== Invalid write of size 8
==18345==    at 0x400F26: Node::addLeft(int) (Ex9.2.cpp:264)
==18345==    by 0x401182: main (Ex9.2.cpp:360)
==18345==  Address 0x5ab61f8 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
==18345==    at 0x4C2F24B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18345==    by 0x402603: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Node, std::allocator<Node>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::deallocate(std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Node, std::allocator<Node>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:110)
==18345==    by 0x4023DC: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Node, std::allocator<Node>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Node, std::allocator<Node>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Node, std::allocator<Node>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:517)
==18345==    by 0x40211D: std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Node, std::allocator<Node>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr() (allocated_ptr.h:72)
==18345==    by 0x402885: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Node, std::allocator<Node>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_destroy() (shared_ptr_base.h:539)
==18345==    by 0x401649: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:167)
==18345==    by 0x40135C: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:659)
==18345==    by 0x401315: std::__shared_ptr<Node, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:925)
==18345==    by 0x401331: std::shared_ptr<Node>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==18345==    by 0x400F19: Node::addLeft(int) (Ex9.2.cpp:262)
==18345==    by 0x401182: main (Ex9.2.cpp:360)
```

Do you have an idea about this error? 
Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: You create a `shared_ptr` temporary, then extract and store the underlying raw pointer. At the semicolon, the temporary is destroyed and deletes the newly created node, leaving `left` dangling. Then your program dereferences this now-dangling pointer, therefore exhibiting undefined behavior.

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you very much for your explanation. I changed left member from a Node* to a shared_ptr<Node>. I guess now the  temporary is still destroyed at the semicolon but the newly created Node object is not destroyed, as the ownership has been transferred to left member. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

. I changed left member from a Node* to a shared_ptr. I guess now the temporary is still destroyed at the semicolon but the newly created Node object is not destroyed, as the ownership has been transferred to left member.

Comment: You should delete this an encourage Igor to write an answer, or if he does not, you can write your own answer using his suggestion.  But as it stands, this is no answer.