# Invalid read for map with a smart pointer value

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a class that defines a map object as follows:

// AwesomeType.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Fxt
{
namespace AnotherNamespace
{
class AwesomeType
{
    int Aid;
    ...
  public:
    AwesomeType(const int id) : Aid { id } {}

    int getId() const { return Aid; }
};
}
}
```

// Test.h

```
#pragma once

#include "AwesomeType.h"

#include <map>
#include <memory>

namespace Fxt
{
namespace AnotherNamespace
{
class Test
{
  std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<AwesomeType>> testMap;

public:
  void add(std::shared_ptr<AwesomeType>& toSave);
};
}
}
```

// Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

using namespace Fxt::AnotherNamespace;

void Test::add(std::shared_ptr<AwesomeType>& toSave)
{
  testMap.insert( { toSave->getId(), toSave } );
}
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

using namespace Fxt::AnotherNamespace;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  auto tester { std::make_shared<Test>() };

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    auto aweSomeStuff { std::make_shared<AwesomeType>(i) };

    tester->add(aweSomeStuff);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The minimal code above works well but my code gives me a segmentation fault check below.

VS Code on the other hand shows that mModelFaces is invalid. (Uninitialized I think, but why?). The modelFace object is valid though.

[image]

I'm not sure what's going on, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Snippets of the actual code:
// SheetMetalFeature.h

```
#pragma once

#include <ostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

#include "ModelTypes.h"
#include "../../include/sheet-metal-component/face/ModelFace.h"
#include "../../include/sheet-metal-component/bend/ModelBend.h"

#include <TopoDS_Shape.hxx>

namespace Fxt
{
namespace SheetMetalComponent
{
    using FaceID = Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::ModelTypes::FaceID;

    class SheetMetalFeature
    {
        std::map<FaceID, std::shared_ptr<Face::ModelFace>> mModelFaces;
        std::map<FaceID, std::shared_ptr<Bend::ModelBend>> mModelBends;
        
        ...
    public:
        SheetMetalFeature() = default;
        void addModelFace(std::shared_ptr<Face::ModelFace>& modelFace);
        ...
    };
}
}
```

Snippet of add method.

```
#include "../../include/sheet-metal-component/SheetMetalFeature.h"
#include "../../include/sheet-metal-component/bend/BendFeature.h"

using namespace Fxt::SheetMetalComponent;

void SheetMetalFeature::addModelFace(std::shared_ptr<Face::ModelFace>& modelFace)
{
    mModelFaces.insert( { modelFace->getFaceId(), modelFace } );
}
```

The actual error message :

```
==13374== Invalid read of size 8
==13374==    at 0x46EACA: std::__shared_ptr<std::map<unsigned int, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::get() const (shared_ptr_base.h:1308)
==13374==    by 0x46D451: std::__shared_ptr_access<std::map<unsigned int, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2, false, false>::_M_get() const (shared_ptr_base.h:1019)
==13374==    by 0x46BC95: std::__shared_ptr_access<std::map<unsigned int, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2, false, false>::operator->() const (shared_ptr_base.h:1013)
==13374==    by 0x468BF2: Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::SheetMetalFeature::addModelFace(std::shared_ptr<Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace>&) (SheetMetalFeature.cpp:14)
==13374==    by 0x469212: Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::SheetMetalFeature::assignFaceAttributes(unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<TopoDS_Shape>&) (SheetMetalFeature.cpp:95)
==13374==    by 0x465B1B: Fxt::CadFileReader::IgesFileReader::extractFaces(std::shared_ptr<Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::SheetMetalFeature>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (IgesFileReader.cpp:51)
==13374==    by 0x461163: init() (cadFileReaderTest.cpp:18)
==13374==    by 0x46130A: main (cadFileReaderTest.cpp:35)
==13374==  Address 0x30 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13374== 
==13374== 
==13374== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==13374==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x30
==13374==    at 0x46EACA: std::__shared_ptr<std::map<unsigned int, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::get() const (shared_ptr_base.h:1308)
==13374==    by 0x46D451: std::__shared_ptr_access<std::map<unsigned int, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2, false, false>::_M_get() const (shared_ptr_base.h:1019)
==13374==    by 0x46BC95: std::__shared_ptr_access<std::map<unsigned int, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2, false, false>::operator->() const (shared_ptr_base.h:1013)
==13374==    by 0x468BF2: Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::SheetMetalFeature::addModelFace(std::shared_ptr<Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::Face::ModelFace>&) (SheetMetalFeature.cpp:14)
==13374==    by 0x469212: Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::SheetMetalFeature::assignFaceAttributes(unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<TopoDS_Shape>&) (SheetMetalFeature.cpp:95)
==13374==    by 0x465B1B: Fxt::CadFileReader::IgesFileReader::extractFaces(std::shared_ptr<Fxt::SheetMetalComponent::SheetMetalFeature>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (IgesFileReader.cpp:51)
==13374==    by 0x461163: init() (cadFileReaderTest.cpp:18)
==13374==    by 0x46130A: main (cadFileReaderTest.cpp:35)
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740975/valgrind-throws-invalid-write-of-size-8-using-smart-pointers

Comment: Thanks, @IronMan. The link you shared seems to be different from my case. Or I guess I'm failing to map the solution into this situation.

Comment: Any globals involved in this code? `testMap` might be uninitialised because it's global and some other piece of code is trying to use it before it's initialised.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Your stack trace shows `operator->` being called, but there is no such call in the code you have shown. On the other hand, `toSave.getId()` shouldn't compile since `getId()` is not a member of `shared_ptr`. Are you sure the *real* code isn't using `toSave->getId()` instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau that was a typing error.

Comment: @john there are no global variables.

Comment: @Minathe Then unless you are doing something very 'advanced' it's impossible for `testMap` to be uninitialised.

Comment: @Minathe The problem here is that there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Try to produce a [mre].

Comment: Ok @john I created a minimal example and it works perfectly fine. The actual code is advanced but its structure is as in the example snippets.

Comment: @john I have added a little snippet of my actual code. shoukd you need more info I'm happy to provide

Comment: @Minathe You've missed **reproducible** in between minimal and example.

Comment: @user7860670 please help me understand that part

Comment: The minimal code doesn't produce the same problem. It works fine thats the challenge

Comment: @Minathe There must be *some* minimum code that reproduces the problem. You should make the effort to find it. By doing so there's a good chance you will discover the problem yourself.

Comment: @Minathe To me the most obvious possibility is that `modelFace` is the shared pointer equivalent of null. That would crash your code.

Comment: Thank you all. @john I finally found the problem. I create the `SheetMetalFeature` `shared_ptr<>` object and did not allocate memory for it with `make_shared<>()`. That is why the maps are invalid